# Lottery program with JButtons and Action Listeners

Tags: actionlistener

I want to create a lottery program.

There are supposed to be 35 numbers to choose from and you will only be able to pick 7. Therefore, I've created 35 JButtons. When you click on a JButton, it will take the value of it using Action Command and outputs the value using a JLabel.

Button number one has the value 1, button number two has the value 2 and so on.

Here is the problem though: When I click on my button, it takes the value of it (for example 12) and then it sets a JLabel to display "12". But when I click ANOTHER button after that, it CHANGES the first value instead of displaying a NEW number.

I suppose it's similar to when someone wants to use the Scanner and you use NextInt();. I basically want to be able to select another number after the first one.

Help would be appreciated since I've basically tried everything.

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;



public class Firstclass implements ActionListener {
final static String BUTTONPANEL = "Play the lottery";
final static String TEXTPANEL = "Discover nuclear physics";
final static String BUTTONPANEL2 = "Zomg free food";

final static int extraWindowWidth = 200;
final static int extraWindowHeight = 500;

//Lotto buttons
JButton b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,
b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12,

b13,b14,b15,b16,b17,b18,
b19,b20,b21,b22,b23,b24,

b25,
b26,b27,b28,b29,b30,b31,b32
,b33,b34,b35;

//Labels
JLabel lbl1,lbl2,lbl3,lbl4,lbl5,lbl6,lbl7,info;

public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.LEFT);




    //First panel
    JPanel card1 = new JPanel() {
        //Make the panel wider than it really needs, so
        //the window's wide enough for the tabs to stay
        //in one row.
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Dimension size = super.getPreferredSize();
            size.width += extraWindowWidth;
            size.height += extraWindowHeight;
            return size;
        }
    };
    //Setting THESE particular JButtons to the first actionlistener
    ActionListener FirstListener = new FirstListener();

    //Adding and configuring the JButtons
    b1 = new JButton(Integer.toString(1));
    b1.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b1);

    b2 = new JButton(Integer.toString(2));
    b2.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b2);

    b3 = new JButton(Integer.toString(3));
    b3.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b3);

    b4 = new JButton(Integer.toString(4));
    b4.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b4);

    b5 = new JButton(Integer.toString(5));
    b5.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b5);

    b6 = new JButton(Integer.toString(6));
    b6.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b6);

    b7 = new JButton(Integer.toString(7));
    b7.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b7);

    b8 = new JButton(Integer.toString(8));
    b8.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b8);

    b9 = new JButton(Integer.toString(9));
    b9.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b9);

    b10 = new JButton(Integer.toString(10));
    b10.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b10.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b10);

    b11 = new JButton(Integer.toString(11));
    b11.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b11.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b11);

    b12 = new JButton(Integer.toString(12));
    b12.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b12.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b12);

    b13 = new JButton(Integer.toString(13));
    b13.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b13.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b13);

    b14 = new JButton(Integer.toString(14));
    b14.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b14.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b14);

    b15 = new JButton(Integer.toString(15));
    b15.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b15.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b15);

    b16 = new JButton(Integer.toString(16));
    b16.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b16.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b16);

    b17 = new JButton(Integer.toString(17));
    b17.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b17.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b17);

    b18 = new JButton(Integer.toString(18));
    b18.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b18.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b18);

    b19 = new JButton(Integer.toString(19));
    b19.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b19.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b19);

    b20 = new JButton(Integer.toString(20));
    b20.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b20.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b20);

    b21 = new JButton(Integer.toString(21));
    b21.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b21.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b21);

    b22 = new JButton(Integer.toString(22));
    b22.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b22.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b22);

    b23 = new JButton(Integer.toString(23));
    b23.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b23.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b23);

    b24 = new JButton(Integer.toString(24));
    b24.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b24.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b24);

    b25 = new JButton(Integer.toString(25));
    b25.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b25.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b25);

    b26 = new JButton(Integer.toString(26));
    b26.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b26.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b26);

    b27 = new JButton(Integer.toString(27));
    b27.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b27.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b27);

    b28 = new JButton(Integer.toString(28));
    b28.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b28.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b28);

    b29 = new JButton(Integer.toString(29));
    b29.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b29.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b29);

    b30 = new JButton(Integer.toString(30));
    b30.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b30.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b30);

    b31 = new JButton(Integer.toString(31));
    b31.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b31.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b31);

    b32 = new JButton(Integer.toString(32));
    b32.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b32.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b32);

    b33 = new JButton(Integer.toString(33));
    b33.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b33.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b33);

    b34 = new JButton(Integer.toString(34));
    b34.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b34.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b34);

    b35 = new JButton(Integer.toString(35));
    b35.addActionListener(FirstListener);
    b35.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    card1.add(b35);


    info = new JLabel("Your numbers are: ");
    card1.add(info);

    lbl1 = new JLabel("");
    card1.add(lbl1);

    lbl2 = new JLabel("");
    card1.add(lbl2);

    lbl3 = new JLabel("");
    card1.add(lbl3);

    lbl4 = new JLabel("");
    card1.add(lbl4);

    lbl5 = new JLabel("");
    card1.add(lbl5);

    lbl6 = new JLabel("");
    card1.add(lbl6);

    lbl7 = new JLabel("");
    card1.add(lbl7);



    //Second panel

    JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
    card2.add(new JTextField("TextField", 20));


    //Third panel
    JPanel card3 = new JPanel();
    card3.add(new JButton("Hardy harr"));



    tabbedPane.addTab(BUTTONPANEL, card1);
    tabbedPane.addTab(TEXTPANEL, card2);
    tabbedPane.addTab(BUTTONPANEL2, card3);

    pane.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}



/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event dispatch thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Slutuppgift");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



    //Create and set up the content pane.
    Firstclass demo = new Firstclass();
    demo.addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());

    //Display the window.
    //frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(500,700);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Use an appropriate Look and Feel */
    try {
        //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    /* Turn off metal's use of bold fonts */
    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);


    //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
private class FirstListener implements ActionListener {

    /** This method will be invoked when a button is clicked */

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

      if (e.getSource() == b1 || e.getSource()==b2 || e.getSource()==b3||
              e.getSource()==b4 || e.getSource()==b5 || e.getSource()==b6 ||
              e.getSource()==b7 || e.getSource()==b8 ||
              e.getSource()==b9 || e.getSource()==b10 ||
              e.getSource()==b11 || e.getSource()==b12 || e.getSource()==b13 ||
              e.getSource()==b14 || e.getSource()==b15 || e.getSource()==b16 ||
              e.getSource()==b17 || e.getSource()==b18 || e.getSource()==b19 ||
              e.getSource()==b20 || e.getSource()==b21 || e.getSource()==b22 ||
              e.getSource()==b23 || e.getSource()==b24 || e.getSource()==b25 ||
              e.getSource()==b26 || e.getSource()==b27 || e.getSource()==b28 ||
              e.getSource()==b29 || e.getSource()==b30 || e.getSource()==b31 ||
              e.getSource()==b32 || e.getSource()==b33 || e.getSource()==b34 ||
              e.getSource()==b35) {lbl1.setText(e.getActionCommand());}
              }

      }

private class SecondListener implements ActionListener {


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent d) {

     if (d.getSource() == b1 || d.getSource()==b2 || d.getSource()==b3||
          d.getSource()==b4 || d.getSource()==b5 || d.getSource()==b6 ||
          d.getSource()==b7 || d.getSource()==b8 ||
          d.getSource()==b9 || d.getSource()==b10 ||
          d.getSource()==b11 || d.getSource()==b12 || d.getSource()==b13 ||
          d.getSource()==b14 || d.getSource()==b15 || d.getSource()==b16 ||
          d.getSource()==b17 || d.getSource()==b18 || d.getSource()==b19 ||
          d.getSource()==b20 || d.getSource()==b21 || d.getSource()==b22 ||
          d.getSource()==b23 || d.getSource()==b24 || d.getSource()==b25 ||
          d.getSource()==b26 || d.getSource()==b27 || d.getSource()==b28 ||
          d.getSource()==b29 || d.getSource()==b30 || d.getSource()==b31 ||
          d.getSource()==b32 || d.getSource()==b33 || d.getSource()==b34 ||
          d.getSource()==b35) {lbl2.setText(d.getActionCommand());}
          }


}



@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}`

Comment: Wow. 35 individual button variables instead of an array of buttons!

Comment: your question is very broad, try and narrow it down to the particular piece of code you are struggling with not your whole program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your listener needs to know which label to change. Learn how to use arrays and then your code can be something like (pseudo code)

```
int labelToChange = 0;
JLabel labels[];

listener()
{
    // This is actually bad: using the GUI as the "source" of data
    // but in this case there are so many other issues this is the least
    // of your problems...
    //
    if (labelToChange < 7) {
        labels[labelToChange++] = e.getSource().getText();
    } else {
        // ERROR - too many buttons pressed
    }
 }
}
```